# Can't clone repo despite successful authentication

Tags: git, github, ssh

I'm on a mac and trying to clone a repo I created on another machine with a private github account.

I went through the typical ssh key steps but for whatever reason I still cannot clone using ssh.

when I run:

```
ssh -T git@github.com-<private account>
```

I get

```
Hi <private account>! You've successfully authenticated, but GitHub does not provide shell access.
```

My ~/.ssh/config

```
Host github.com
 HostName github.com
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa
 IdentitiesOnly yes

Host github.com-<private account>
 HostName github.com
 User git
 IdentityFile ~/.ssh/id_rsa_****
 IdentitiesOnly yes
```

When I clone:

```
Cloning into 'my repo'...
ERROR: Repository not found.
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

I don't get anything out of the ordinary from:

```
ssh -v git@github.com-<private account>
```

The repo was created with git 1.9.1, while I'm trying to clone with 2.11.0. Could that make a difference?

Comment: What command are you using to clone?

Comment: git clone git@github.com:<myaccount>/<my repo>.git, which is the url supplied by the clone or download button on github

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference of Git version should not matter.

But if you want to clone with the right ssh authentication, you need to use the right ssh URL:

```
git clone github.com-<private account>:<auser>/<aproject.git>
```

Comment: What's the difference between <private account> and <auser> ?

Comment: @C-RAD I just meant to use the exact string you put in your ~/.ssh/config file as 'Host'. That identifies the server. After that, the path of the repo is usually  a user account/a repo

Comment: I created that block in the config file to use a different key with my private account. Am i correct in believing the host should be defined as github.com-<github.com account>? When clicked, The 'clone or download' button on github displays git@github.com:<mygithubaccount>/<my repo>.git as the url to use for cloning with ssh.

Comment: @C-RAD Host can be anything: xxx. The url would be xxx:<asuer>/<arepo>. As long as the public key matching the private key referenced under the xxx line, that would authenticate you with the right account. Not need for the `git@` part: your config file already specify the user git.

Comment: OK I got it. I thought the 'Host' line of the config file was meant to point to the github account, not to define a custom name for the host. I was successful with git clone github.com-<myaccount>:<myaccount>/<repo>